# Downloading batch reports from google analytics API v4

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I am trying to get a report for 3 months, for this, I need to make multiple requests and append the results to a list because API only returns `100,000` rows per request. There is a variable returned from the API named `nextPageToken` which I need to pass into the next query to get the next `100,000` rows of the report. I am having a difficult time trying to do this.

Here is my code:

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    '''Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

    Returns:
      An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    '''
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    # Build the service object.
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    return analytics


list = [] 




def get_report(analytics, pageTokenVariable):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'pageSize': 100000,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '90daysAgo', 'endDate': 'yesterday'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:adClicks'}, {'expression': 'ga:impressions'}, {'expression': 'ga:adCost'}, {'expression': 'ga:CTR'}, {'expression': 'ga:CPC'}, {'expression': 'ga:costPerTransaction'}, {'expression': 'ga:transactions'}, {'expression': 'ga:transactionsPerSession'}, {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'}],
                    "pageToken": pageTokenVariable,
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery'}, {'name': 'ga:campaign'}, {'name': 'ga:adGroup'}, {'name': 'ga:adwordsCustomerID'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}],
                    'orderBys': [{'fieldName': 'ga:impressions', 'sortOrder': 'DESCENDING'}],
                    'dimensionFilterClauses': [{

                        'filters': [{

                            'dimension_name': 'ga:adwordsCustomerID',
                            'operator': 'EXACT',
                            'expressions': 'abc',
                            'not': 'True'
                        }]
                    }],
                    'dimensionFilterClauses': [{

                        'filters': [{

                            'dimension_name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery',
                            'operator': 'EXACT',
                            'expressions': '(not set)',
                            'not': 'True'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
        }
    ).execute()


analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
response = get_report(analytics, "0")

for report in response.get('reports', []):
    pagetoken = report.get('nextPageToken', None)
    print(pagetoken)
    #------printing the pagetoken here returns `100,000` which is expected

    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get(
        'metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
        # create dict for each row
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

        # fill dict with dimension header (key) and dimension value (value)
        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            dict[header] = dimension

        # fill dict with metric header (key) and metric value (value)
        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                # set int as int, float a float
                if ',' in value or ',' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
        list.append(dict)
      # Append that data to a list as a dictionary

# pagination function

    while pagetoken:  # This says while there is info in the nextPageToken get the data, process it and add to the list

        response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)
        pagetoken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']
        print(pagetoken)
        #------printing the pagetoken here returns `200,000` as is expected but the data being pulled is the same as for the first batch and so on. While in the loop the pagetoken is being incremented but it does not retrieve new data
        for row in rows:
                # create dict for each row
            dict = {}
            dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
            dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

            # fill dict with dimension header (key) and dimension value (value)
            for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
                dict[header] = dimension

            # fill dict with metric header (key) and metric value (value)
            for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
                for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                    # set int as int, float a float
                    if ',' in value or ',' in value:
                        dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                    else:
                        dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
            list.append(dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print(df)  # Append that data to a list as a dictionary
df.to_csv('full_dataset.csv', encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Where is my mistake trying to pass the pagetoken?

[Here is the documentation for the `pageToken` from Google.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportrequest)

Comment: Take a look at this article about [pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#pagination). You will need to interrogate the the `report` for a `nextPageToken` and then include that as the `pageToken` in the subsequent request. The  API returns a maximum of 100,000 rows per request, no matter how many you ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're updating the pagetoken in `pagetoken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']` but shouldn't you also update `rows` in the while loop with new data?

Something like this.

```
    while pagetoken:
        response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)
        pagetoken = response['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken')
        for report in reponse.get('reports', []):
            rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
            for row in rows:
```

Comment: I do not know, that is why I am searching for an answer, the documentation does not explain it properly. It only states to update the `pageToken`.

Comment: Added code example. Unable to test it but to me `rows` needs to be updated otherwise you'll process the same data over and over.

Comment: Now I get `KeyError: 'nextPageToken'` at the line `response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)`. The data seems to be pulling correct now, it just does not stop when the `nextPageToken` is no longer there. But why? I do have the `while pagetoken` condition.

Comment: Thank you, that worked out! So as I understand: the problem was that even thought I have the right `nextPageToken` I used to query the same report? And the difference between using `get` for the `pagetoken` is that it deos not throw an error if it does not find it?

Comment: Correct. `get` returns `None` instead of raising an Exception.